# Se puede hacer un lector de código de barras web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenas tengo que hacer un proyecto web en el cual pueda leer código de barras  por la cámara del móvil, tiene que ser web, osea una página web que sea capaz de leer un código de barras. mi pregunta: ¿se puede hacer? Yo hice algo ya, pero va como el culo de mil fotos que saco lee 1 dejo el enlace: https://invyasiel.github.io/scanner-web/ 
está hecho con quagga pero o bien yo no se usarlo o bien esque va mal de por si.

**¿Que quiero conseguir?**
Mi objetivo es tener una web sencilla donde simplemente se vea un botón el cual ejecute la cámara del móvil y tomando una foto o sin tomarla me lea un código de barras devolviendo el resultado en en un div por ejemplo.

Comment: No entiendo cual está siendo tu limitación para leerlo en una página web, si podes explica mejor eso!

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal mi limitación es que no se como  sé como hacerlo osea no se si existe algún framework o librería web.

Comment: Tienes muchas implementaciones para usar. Mira esta, por ejemplo: https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS

Comment: Gracias, pero quaggaJS no me funciona correctamente lo puse en la pregunta